# Model selection: where to start?

Tags: modeling, model-selection

For a general modeling problem, there are literally at least a dozen choices of statistical and algorithmic models to choose from. Off the top of my head, choices could be: regression (and its variants), neural networks (and its variants), SVM (and its variants), random forests (and its variants), etc.

So what I'm asking about isn't much about what is referred to 'model selection'. I'm looking for a guide that can help me (intelligently) choose candidate models. Or is this process more of an art? I'm not looking for models specialized for certain data types. I'm looking for models that generically model tabular data.

I tried consulting with Google but it wasn't of much help. Surely, there must be a guide on how to begin the model selection process.

Comment: What are you selecting a model for? Prediction, inference, forecasting, etc. What is the distribution of the outcome? How many features are available for analysis and how will the target model be applied? What is the substantive question? It's like a doctor complaining that, when presented with a patient, he doesn't know whether to grab a scalpel, a blood pressure cuff, or  a defibrillator.

Comment: these are the kinds of questions i would expect answered in some guide for the modelling process. i'm only looking for some kind of (high level) reference as an answer to my question as i understand my question is broad.

Comment: A good reference is Elements of Statistical Learning.

Comment: thanks but that kind of reference is not what i'm looking for since it's (just) a compliation of methods.

what i'm looking for is something along the lines of what can be found on ~pg. 69.
http://www.boozallen.com/media/file/The-Field-Guide-to-Data-Science.pdf

Comment: Given that you are facing difficulty in identifying models, I will suggest that your proposed example is a type of writing that is not up to the level of sophistication necessary to adequately apply these models. I will re-emphasize that the Tibshirani text is considered one of the best in the field, and that by working through the exercises, and understanding the nuances of the respective gradient descent algorithms, you could substantially improve your limited grasp of this subject.

Comment: i know it's a good book. i have gone through such a process of working through such methods. i do understand some work better on certain problems than others and i'm just trying to find a summary of model pros/cons and applicability. i could probably assemble my own (non-expert) answer if i go though the Tibshirani text.

Comment: I think it is unfortunate that this question was put on hold: statistics has room for both "on the dance floor" perspectives as well as "from the mezzanine" ones, and asking and answering questions about how to approach modeling itself (as opposed how to approach a specific model) is a valuable process... one with different aims questions of narrow scope.

Answer (score 6):

**Start with your substantive non-statistical research question.**

Be comfortable with what question(s) you are trying to answer, and what the form of a satisfactory answer would look like. *Then* go looking for models.

If you commit to an analytic model (statistical or otherwise) and then fit your research question and study design into *that*, you are constraining *a priori* the form of answer that your analysis will produce in ways that are deeply ontological both in terms of expectation (what the world looks like) and ideological (how you value it). To give a simple and cartoonish example: committing to 'flat' (non-hierarchical/non-multilevel) regression models biases your analysis away from considering *group context*. A [raft of logical fallacies might follow](https://ajph.aphapublications.org/doi/abs/10.2105/AJPH.88.2.216), and certainly ideological positions (such as Margaret Thatcher's oft-quoted direction of where to gaze "[they are casting their problems on society and who is society? There is no such thing! There are individual men and women and there are families and no government can do anything except through people and people look to themselves first](https://blogs.spectator.co.uk/coffeehouse/2013/04/margaret-thatcher-in-quotes/)") could be reified in the seeming of a mathematical neutrality.

In the sciences, *all* our models are false, being convenient fictions that employ until we run into the boundaries of their convenience. To paraphrase Richard Levins, we will find the truth at the intersection of independent lies. So triangulate with (radically) different forms of model building: game theoretic models versus regression models versus differential equation models versus loop analysis models etc.

See this chapter for some deliciousness: Awerbuch, T., Kiszewski, A. E., and Levins, R. (2002). [*Environmental change, climate and health: issues and research methods*](https://www.fetchbook.info/compare.do?search=9780521114028), chapter Surprise, nonlinearity and complex behavior, pages 197–219. Cambridge University Press, New York, NY.

Also, Levins, R. (1966). [The strategy of model building in population biology](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27836590). *American Scientist*, 54(4):421–431 is worth a read, as is the [series](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3037250) [of](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3037251) [critical](https://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1092/) [responses](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/498475) [to](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/508099) [it](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-008-9366-y).

Comment: great advice. i've already identified my question. i just want a reference that summarizes models that could answer my question. 'flat' analysis is a good place to start to see what is possible. more sophisticated models can be explored later that perhaps address particular aspects of the data or to /better/ answer the question but that is not my concern now.

Comment: @MajidalDosari it might be worth sitting down with a quantitative modeler and talk about approaches over warm caffeinated beverage.

Comment: What happened to : "*To consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often merely to ask him to conduct a post mortem examination. He can perhaps say what the experiment died of.*"? Formulating your substantive non-statistical research question is desirable but if the question cannot be answer by the available methods and/or data is useless.

Comment: @usεr11852 Is not useless: that drives development new analytic approaches. We need to be careful not to conflate the map with the landscape, or the model with reality... even when the model is quite good. To riff off Levins some more: just because we can quite usefully represent sound over time with the Fast Fourrier Transform by decomposing a signal into an infinite sum of sine-waves at all the frequencies, **does not** mean that when I sing there are an infinite number of sine-wave generating membranes in my mouth set into motion. Also: tee-hee... post mortem.

Comment: The thread is about model selection, not the development of new analytic approaches.

Comment: @usεr11852 I buy that conditional on the assumption that selection of modeling approach bears no relationship to development of new ways of modeling. :)

Comment: No probs! I can live with that! :D